# 7.500000e+04 , how can i figure out if this value is in thousands or million?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am learning pandas for analysis of data, and i came across describe() which gives us min,max,count etc. I executed the function for sales_price column only.

For min value i got 7.500000e+04. I wish to understand whether this value is in thousands or millions? Is there any way to find out?

Comment: Do a bit of research on ‘e (engineering) notation’ or ‘scientific notation’.  This will tell you how to read this number.

Comment: use scientific notation and round()

Comment: you can format it as string `print("{:f}".format(7.500000e+04))` and you see `75000.000000`

Comment: you can always compare it `print( 7.500000e+04 >= 1_000_000 )`

Answer (score 2):

Your number means 75000.

The notation "[A]e[B]" means shifting the decimal point of A B digits to the right. So if B is positive (as in your example), we shift it to the right. Otherwise, we shift it to the left.

If you want to learn more, the keyword is [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know `e` notation then you can still try to use it.

You can reformat it as string

```
print("{:f}".format(7.500000e+04))
```

and you see

```
75000.000000
```

You can also compare it with `thousand` and/or `million`

```
7.500000e+04 >= 1_000_000:
```

like

```
value = 7.500000e+04

if value >= 1_000_000:
    print('milions or more')
elif value >= 1_000:
    print('thousands')
elif value >= 100:
    print('hundreds')
else:
    print('tens or less')
```